# Compute the n-simplex numbers in Python?

Tags: python, math

Not sure where this goes. The n-simplex numbers are (as I understand them) a generalization of tetrahedral and triangular numbers to d dimensions: http://oeis.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytopic_numbers. My naive attempt at translating these formulas  (with help from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098311/is-there-a-way-to-generalize-the-polygonal-and-pyramidal-numbers-to-higher-dimen) into Python code for generating these numbers is below:

```
def simplex(maxim, s):
    result = s
    for i in range(1, maxim-1):
        result = result * (i + 1) #?

    result //= factorial(maxim)
    return result
```

I'd like this function to return the maxim-dimensional s-th simplex number, but as you can probably tell, I am a bit confused as to how to actually implement this.

Comment: I think `math.comb(maxim + s - 1, maxim)` gives you what you want, at least assuming Python >= 3.8. For earlier Python versions, use `factorial(maxim + s - 1) // factorial(maxim) // factorial(s - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
def simplex(maxim, s):
    result = s
    for i in range(1, maxim):
        result *= i + s
    result //= factorial(maxim)
    return result
```